# IntelliJ IDEA only opens .forms in text now?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jform

IntelliJ is only opening my .forms as plain text. They seem to work fine when I run the Jar, but I can't edit them because I only see this when I double click the files:

http://gyazo.com/bee9b50bf5b55a9962c54adc5e6f3157.png

It sometimes did this before, but now it's *always* doing it and restarting—my usual remedy—isn't working.

Comment: that's usually a file that's corrupt in some way. As the flood of warnings at the start indicate.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making new forms and pasting in the old code externally. I hope this is fixed soon in case it happens again.